# Is it possible to declare variables in VHDL with an asterisk?

Tags: variables, vhdl, ram, variable-declaration

Quite new to VHDL here, so I'm not entirely sure if this is feasible at all, but here goes:

In my test code for some RAM, I have 2 8-bit std_logic_vector variables `wdata_a_v` and `wdata_b_v`. This is all I need for the current setup, but if the ratio of read to write data length changes, I will need more variables of the name `wdata_*_v`. I'm trying to write the code generically so that it will function for any amount of these variables, but I don't want to declare 26 of them in the code when I will likely only need a few.

It would be nice if there was a way to declare a variable like so:

```
variable wdata_*_v : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
```

that would, behind the scenes, declare all of the variables that fit this framework so that I could write a loop without worrying about running out of variables.

If there's a way to write a function or procedure etc. to make this work, that would be excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can go with a 2d array, recipe:

```
entity TestHelper is
  generic (n: natural range 2 to 255 := 8);
end TestHelper;

architecture behavioral of TestHelper is
  type array2d is array (n-1 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
   process
     variable a : array2d;
   begin
       a(0)(0) := '0';
   end process;
end architecture behavioral;
```

EDIT: Now to use it and create similar code for each of `wdata_*_v`:

```
process
   variable wdata_v : array2d;
begin
   someLabel: for i in 0 to n-1 generate
       wdata_v(i)(0) := '0';
       x <= y and z;
       ...
   end generate;

   x <= '1';
   ...

   anotherLabel: for i in 1 to n generate
      ...
   end generate;

   ...
end process;
```

Comment: I'm not sure my question was 100% clear. I'm looking for something that will allow me to use wdata_a_v, wdata_r_v, wdata_z_v, etc while only declaring wdata_*_v or something similar. I'm not sure how this 2d array will accomplish that, but as I said, I'm new, so I may be missing something.

Comment: I'm not following the edit, unfortunately. It's declaring an array of std_logic_vectors called wdata_v, but this doesn't seem to allow me to use variables with different names, such as in my previous comment. I certainly appreciate the help, though.

Comment: @user2452645: If each of `wdata_a_v`, `wdata_b_v`, ... is driven by the same business logic, you can use the generate loop to write the logic once and have carbon copies for each letter of the alphabet. If you want to reference the variables by different names, can you use `wdata_v(0)`, `wdata_v(1)`,.. as those distinct names?

Comment: That certainly sounds like it could work. Each variable will likely have a different value; in this case, a random std_logic_vector value from a RNG library. Would I be able to simply declare the wdata_v array to be `others -> '0'`, and then use the wdata_v(0) as separate variables, and assign to them?

Comment: @user2452645 Absolutely. You need `wdata_v := (others => (others => '0'));` or `wdata_v := (others => "00000000");`.

Comment: Ok, this is my first introduction to 2-D arrays. I'll give this a shot and get back to you. Thanks!